# How to connect to date database and how to do INSERT,DELETE and RETRIEVAL using ADO.NET in C#?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, ado.net

I'm a beginner in C# windows application development. Now I want to create a database and to connect to it from my C# program. I would like to do it using ADO.NET Technology.Can any of you show me a guideline for that.As I'm a beginner I want to know the basic steps for that. I'm waiting for your reply. Thanks ..:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [tutorial on connecting c# to sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815481/tutorial-on-connecting-c-sharp-to-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You should try the below links for getting knowledge on ADO.NET

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson01.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DatabaseAcessWithAdoNet1.aspx